# why svn is ignoring my -r argument?

Tags: svn

i'm trying to get the contents of a deleted file.

```
$ svn log -v path_to_file/
...
r123 | user | date
D path_to_file/the_file
```

ok, so it was removed at revision 123.. and added around revision 10 or so.

```
$ svn cat -r 122 svn+ssh://server/repo/path_to_file/the_file
svn: File not found: revision 554, path '/path_to_file/the_file'
$ svn log -r 122 svn+ssh://server/repo/path_to_file/the_file
svn: File not found: revision 554, path '/path_to_file/the_file'
```

why is that? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`svn cat -r xxx <path to file>` isn't working after a file has been deleted;
If you want to get a copy of that file use the following:
`svn copy <path to file>@xxx <path to workspace>` where *xxx* is the revision

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work with the following:

```
svn cat svn+ssh://server/repo/path_to_file/the_file@122
```

This bit me some time ago with a merge command, it seems svn is slowly migrating to '@rev' over '-r rev'.

The log command can take both options but with different results:

```
svn log -v -r 122 svn+ssh://server/repo/path_to_file/the_file@122
svn log svn+ssh://server/repo/path_to_file/the_file@122
```

The first log request will only give log for r122.
The second log command does r122:0

Comment: `@rev` & `-r rev` serve two different purposes. `@rev` looks to a specific revision to find that URL. `-r rev`gives you the content of the URL at that revision. Which is why you have to specify `@rev` to retrieve the log of a deleted directory - if no `@rev` is specified, it acts as though use used `@HEAD`. In the example given here, `svn log svn+ssh://server/repo/path_to_file/the_file@122 -r 122` will produce the same output as `svn log svn+ssh://server/repo/path_to_file/the_file@100 -r 122` (assuming that the file existed in revision 100 as well)